Refrigerator water filter change
Water into the house goes through:

whole house water filter
water softner
RO system
then to the refrigerator.

Is there a need to replace the refrigerator water filter when unit indicates to?
Thanks.

You can ask the refrigerator manufacturer for their recommendation oonsidering your setup. You could also decide not to replace the filter until the taste of the water is unaceptable which, of course, is a judgement call. You could also just replace the filter when indicated and not worry about it.

remove the refrigerator filter
